# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Цель, конечно, не свергнуть власть...

Answer (score 1):

Тире не ставится, если между подлежащим, выраженным существительным, и сказуемым, выраженным инфинитивом, стоит вводное слово или частица НЕ. Здесь есть и то и другое.